# Tagging questions about .aux, .log, .bbl, & similar files

Tags: feature-request, tagging

Two tags, [aux-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aux-files) and [temporary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temporary-files) talk about the non-input/output files used by `*TeX*`.  I propose that we have one, [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files), with two synonyms, because:

- The Texbook talks, I think, only of input, log, auxiliary, and dvi files.  Thus talk of temporary files is not classical.
- Besides also not being classical, "aux-files" suggests that we are talking only of files with a `.aux` extension, while the Texbook uses auxiliary files generally for files output to for later input from by the Tex engine, including with the `.tex` extension.

A minor issue: things like log files and .bbl files may commonly be referred to as auxiliary files, but they are, respectively, not input to and not output from the Tex engine, so they don't fit the above definition.

I've tagged the following [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files), which did not have related tags beforehand:

1. [Include aux file in tex source?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8345/include-aux-file-in-tex-source)
2. [Best script for automatically copying references from a centralised bib file based on aux file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6512/best-script-for-automatically-copying-references-from-a-centralised-bib-file-base)
3. [‘Bundle’ TeX output in a directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/bundle-tex-output-in-a-directory)
4. [Problem with special characters in .toc files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4807/problem-with-special-characters-in-toc-files)

I don't have enough upvotes in any of these tags to propose or vote on these tag synonyms, and I think few enough people have that it would need moderator action to realise my suggestion.  So, should we merge the tags?

Comment: I agree that these tags should be merged. Questions about bbl files should imo be tagged {bibliographies}.

Comment: +1 for merge to `{auxiliary-files}`.

Answer (score 6):

This seems pretty sensible to me. If the question gets a few more up-votes, and nobody raises a concern, I think any of the moderators we could add the proposed synonyms.

**Edit:** I've just added these synonyms.

Answer (score 2):

As Juan added the synonyms, I made the merge, now there are 7 [auxiliary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auxiliary-files) questions. [aux-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aux-files) and [temporary-files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/temporary-files) remain to be synonyms but don't tag a question any more.